# GET of a page on LAN server fails in ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to GET a url from a http server on my LAN using AJAX. The same url loads just fine on firefox, but when doing a GET from the code below it throws a failure.

Please help me figure this out. Here is the code:

```
    <head>
    <title>Display_page</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black">

    <div id="logs" style="width: 100%;height: 100%; background-color: black;position: absolute;color:white;padding:50px;"></div>

    <script>
    for(var i = 0;i<3;i++){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://10.102.132.42/lan.asp',
        method:"GET",
        async:true,
        error:function(){

            $("#logs").html("Failure</br>"+$("#logs").html());
        },
        success:function(){
            $("#logs").html("Success</br>"+$("#logs").html());
        }

    });
}

   </script>
   </body>
```

P.S. I have verified that the server returns http 200 OK response. Since trying the above code I have also tried handling a 200 response using statusCode, but I never see it hitting there. Really lost here.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make a cross domain call. For that you will have to set crossDomain to true.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://10.102.132.42/lan.asp',
    method:"GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    error:function(){
        $("#logs").html("Failure</br>"+$("#logs").html());
    },
    success:function(){
        $("#logs").html("Success</br>"+$("#logs").html());
    }

});
```

Note that this must also be enabled on the server side. For more information refer to: https://d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/

Comment: This might be a really dumb question, but how is this a cross-domain call? The server is on the same LAN, same IP address series. I'll try your suggested changes and see if it helps.

Comment: Domain in this case is defined on webapplication level (not ip or whatever). You are calling from one application to another. This could already be an issue if you are working on your localhost from for example port 44101 to port 44102.